# Animated vector drawable path data

Tags: android

I am trying to create an animated vector drawable. For some reason when I am using the arc path the app crashes but the line commands work fine.

```
<objectAnimator
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
    android:propertyName="pathData"
    android:valueFrom="M 12 3 l0,0 l0,0"
    android:valueTo="M 12 3 a 1,1 0, 1,1 5,5 "
    android:valueType="pathType" />
```

Comment: l 4,0 l 5,5 etc - drawling straight lines work fine but drawing arcs crashes

Comment: ok go to `AnimatedVectorDrawable` documentation and ^F `Note that the paths must be compatible for morphing`